# How do I go about getting the real result for 50%60 in C++

Tags: c++

I please check this problem I'm creating a Time Base app but I'm having problem getting to work around the modulus oper (%) I want the remainder of 50%60 which I'm expecting to output 10 but it just give me the Lhvalues instead i.e 50. How do I go about it.

Here is a part review of the code.

```
void setM(int m){               
if ((m+min)>59){
hour+=((min+m)/60);
min=0;
min=(min+m)%60;
}
else min+=m;
}
```

In the code m is passed in as 50 and min is passed in as 10

How do I get the output to be 10 for min in this equation  min=(min+m)%60;  without reversing the equation i.e
 60%(min+m)

Comment: `50 mod 60` is 50.  That is when 50 is divided by 60 you get 0 remainder 50.

Comment: "which I'm expecting to output 10". Why is that?

Comment: Your code is horribly formatted and makes no sense, since you're using `min`  inside the `if`-condition before assigning it.

Comment: you use min before you assign it any value. And you should maybe check your understanding of the modulus operator, as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

in C++ expression `a % b` returns remainder of division of a by b (if they are positive. For negative numbers sign of result is implementation defined). 
you should do : 60 % 50 if you want to divide by 50
Or, if you want to get mins, i think you don't need to make min=0.

Comment: OP is creating a _"Time Base app"_ mod 50 is probably not what OP wants to do.  There is probably something else wrong with his algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `50 % 60`, you get a remiainder of 50 since 50 cannot be divided by 60.

To get around this error, you can try doing do something like `70 % 60` to get the correct value as a result, since you do not want to use `60 % 50`

This would follow the following logic:

- Find the difference between 60 and `min + m` after `min` is set to zero **if** `min + m`is less than 60. Store it in a variable `var` initially set to zero.
- check if the result is negative; if it is, then set it to positive by multiplying it by -1
- When you do the operation, do `min = ((min + m) + var) % 60;` instead.

****Note: As I am unfamiliar with a **Time Base App** and what its purpose is, this solution may or may not be required, hence **please inform me in the comments before downvoting** if I there is anything wrong with my answer. Thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like you are trying to convert an integral number of minutes to an hour/minute pair. That would look more like this instead:

```
void setM(int m)
{
    hour = m / 60;
    min = m % 60;
}
```

If you are trying to *add* an integral number of minutes to an existing hour/minute pair, it would look more like this:

```
void addM(int m)
{
    int value = (hour * 60) + min;
    value += m;
    hour = value / 60;
    min = value % 60;
}
```

Or

```
void addM(int m)
{
    setM(((hour * 60) + min) + m);
}
```